# Archive all csv files in directory

Tags: python-2.7, csv, zip

I have a python script that creates a few large csv files when it runs (weekly). I want to archive these files in a subdirectory called 'archive' with a datestamp to reference in the future.

The solutions that I've found using zipfile aren't working. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. This is what I have so far:

```
import glob
import zipfile
from datetime import datetime

file_list = [file for file in glob.glob('*.csv')]

output_file = 'Report_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile('archive\\'+output_file, 'w') as zf:
    for n, file in enumerate(file_list):
        zf.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), file.read())
zf.close()
```

I'm geting the following error which I realize is becuase I'm trying to read the file name as the file contents.

```
    zf.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), file.read())

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How do I pass the zf.writestr the content of my csv files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because `file` in:

```
for n, file in enumerate(file_list):
```

is a `str`.  You probably meant to open file:

```
for n, file in enumerate(file_list):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        zf.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), f.read())
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I needed to open the files to read them but wasn't sure how.